# Inline installation deprecated Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I was wondering if there's anything similar to Inline installation of Chrome extensions since it's deprecated  now. Is the only way to install chrome extensions from the webpage "chrome.google.com/webstore/..." or is there another easier way?

Comment: It's the only way. As explained in the official statement Google had to do it because the feature was mostly used by the very bad people who write malware and so on.

Comment: Sad. Alright. Thanks for the insight.